# Find the function that has the following series representation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I encounter this series in an old book of infinite series. The series is as followed:

$1+(\dfrac{1}{2})x^2+(\dfrac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot4})^2x^4+(\dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6})^3x^6+(\dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8})^4x^8...$

Judging from the series, it must be an even function.
Is it possible to find the closed form function for this series. Also, instead of the power of 2 in coefficients, we may have them in n. Do we have a general formula to generate the functions for power of n?

I try to differentiate this series but it doesn't seem to produce anything fruitful.

Comment: The exponents on the coefficients are really annoying. If I am right, by Stirling, the coefficients (with exponents) are asymptotic to $n^{-n/2}$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yeah, you are right, without the exponent things may become much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^2\bigg)^n.$$

Comment: Chin: this is for the general series that I ask right?

Comment: This is for the exact series that you have provided.

Comment: Do you know how to find the closed form function for this series?

Comment: I cannot imagine there should be one.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22summation%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28x%5E2+%28%282n%2B1%29%21%21%2F%282n%29%21%21%29%29%5En%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22n%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Sum%22%2C+%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D+-%3E%22infinity%22) is unable to provide me with anything.

Comment: Not all power series have closed form expression, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have learnt the convergence tests, otherwise I probably will find out whether this series is convergent or divergent.